# R - Plotting 2 different sized variables with different time axis with ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have two variables that are different sizes. These variables were measured on very similar time scales, but they are different by a few days (data spans about half a year). Here are the variables, along with the time axes:

```
data1 # double, length of 229081
time1 # double, length of 229081
data2 # double, length of 230842
time2 # double, length of 230842
```

I want to plot these two variables as line plots on the same graph using ggplot. I've tried the following but to no avail:

```
data = data.frame(data1, data2) 
qplot(time2, data, color=colors, scale_colour_identity(guide="legend"),
          geom=c("line", "line"))
```

I feel like the above should work, since I'm using the bigger time axis, which encompasses the smaller data set. I tried looking for a similar question on stackoverflow, but couldn't quite find it.

Comment: I think there are two flaws in your attempted code: the first is of form (different sizes of data1 and data2), which in the best scenario will throw some unnecessary NAs. The second one is of substance, as you pretended to plot `time2` and `data` as if they were from matching observations, and they aren't necessarily so (think what happened if sizes were the same and I "shuffled" the order of `time2`). Try to plot each different variable (data1 and data2) against its corresponding time (time1 and time2), that solves both flaws.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to pass an independent data frame to an additional call to `geom_line`:

As you didn't provide any reproducible example (it's good to do so!):

```
data1<-data.frame(d1=runif(100),t1=sample(1:1000,100))
data2<-data.frame(d1=runif(98),t1=sample(1:2000,98))
```

Then you can plot:

```
ggplot(data1,aes(d1,t1))+geom_line()+geom_line(data=data2,aes(d1,t1,color="red"))
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! I'll make sure to provide reproducible data next time.